# jQuery image slider scrolls page to top when changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've just started to get into jQuery, so I apologise for the bad coding in advance. I just recognised that whenever I scroll a bit down so that just a bit of the jQuery image slider is visible on the top of the page, it scrolls me automatically back to top when the jQuery image slider changes the picture. But when I am as far down on the page that the slider isn't visible at all or when I barely scroll down so that the most part of the slider is still on the screen, it doesn't scroll me back to top.
I would appreciate any help since I am not able to find the issue.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('#back_to_top').click(function()
 {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});
  return false;
 });

  // Nav bar drop down code
  $('#deals_a').hover(function(){
    $('#deals_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
  });

  if(!$('#deals_dropdown').is(':hover')){
    $('#deals').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#deals_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    });
  } else {
    $('#deals_dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#deals_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    });
  };

  $('#services_a').hover(function(){
    $('#services_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
  });

  if(!$('#services_dropdown').is(':hover')){
    $('#services').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#services_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    });
  } else {
    $('#services_dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#services_dropdown').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    });
  };

  // Slider button code
  $('.slider_button').hover(function(){
    $('.slider_button').removeClass('active_button');
    $(this).addClass('active_button');
    $('.slide').hide();
    $($('#slider').children()[$(this).index()]).show();
  });




// Slider code
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Set options
  var speed = 500; // Fade speed
  var autoswitch_speed = 4000; // Auto slider speed

  var  myInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);

  // Add initial active class
  $('.slide').first().addClass('active');

  // Hide all slides
  $('.slide').hide();

  // Show first slide
  $('.active').show();


  // show the first node
  ($($('#slider_button_container').children()[0])).addClass('active_button');



  var counter = 1;

  // Switch to next slide
 function nextSlide(){
   clearInterval(myInterval);
   $('.slider_button').removeClass('active_button');
   ($($('#slider_button_container').children()[counter - 1])).removeClass('active_button');
   ($($('#slider_button_container').children()[counter])).addClass('active_button');
   $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
   if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
     $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
     ($($('#slider_button_container').children()[3])).removeClass('active_button');
     ($($('#slider_button_container').children()[0])).addClass('active_button');
     counter = 0;
   } else {
     $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
   }
   $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
   $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
   $('.active').fadeIn(speed);

   counter = (counter + 1) % 4;
   myInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, autoswitch_speed);
 }
 });
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav_menu{

  height: 98px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav_menu_items{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width:auto;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.nav_menu_items a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;

}

.nav_menu_sup:hover::after{
  content: "\25B2";
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 14px;
}

#back_to_top, #back_to_top img{
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  display:block;
}

.dropdown{
  display:none;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF;
  top:100px;
  line-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.color_1{
  background: #4BB7BE;
}

.color_2{
  background: #2A7287;
}

.dropdown li{
padding: 10px;
;
}

.dropdown li:hover{

}

.dropdown li a{
  color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown li a:hover{
  color: #FFA;
}

#slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -105px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.slide img{
  height: 600px;
}

.darkening_layer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#slider_button_container{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slider_button{
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  float: left;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.slider_button:hover{
  background: #FFF;
}

.active_button{
  background: #FFF;
}

#first_slider_button{

}


#welcome{
  background: #007DCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;

}

#advertise{
  background: #004E7F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #007DCC;
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sea Kozmetik ve Güzellik</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <div id="nav_menu">
          <div id="home" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" href="#">ANASAYFA</a>
          </div>
          <div id="about" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" href="#">HAKKIMIZDA</a>
          </div>
          <div id="deals" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" id="deals_a" href="#">KAMPANYALAR</a>
            <ul id="deals_dropdown" class="dropdown">
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Öğrenci Kampanyaları</a></li>
              <li class="color_2"><a href="#">Epilasyon Kampanyaları</a></li>
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Cilt Bakımı Kampanyaları</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="services" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" id="services_a" href="#">HİZMETLERİMİZ</a>
            <ul id="services_dropdown" class="dropdown">
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Cilt Bakımı</a></li>
              <li class="color_2"><a href="#">Depilasyon</a></li>
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Epilasyon</a></li>
              <li class="color_2"><a href="#">Manikür</a></li>
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Pedikür</a></li>
              <li class="color_2"><a href="#">Tırnak Bakımı</a></li>
              <li class="color_1"><a href="#">Kaş Tasarımı</a></li>
              <li class="color_2"><a href="#">Makyaj</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="products" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" href="#">ÜRÜNLERİMİZ</a>
          </div>
          <div id="gallery" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" href="#">GALERİ</a>
          </div>
          <div id="contact" class="nav_menu_items">
            <a class="nav_menu_sup" href="#">İLETİŞİM</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Picture size must be 1519px x 600px -->
        <div id="slider">
          <div id="first_slide" class="slide">
            <div class="darkening_layer"></div>
            <img src="images/slide_7.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div id="second_slide" class="slide">
            <div class="darkening_layer"></div>
            <img src="images/slide_8.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div id="third_slide" class="slide">
            <div class="darkening_layer"></div>
            <img src="images/slide_9.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

          <div id="fourth_slide" class="slide">
            <div class="darkening_layer"></div>
            <img src="images/slide_10.jpg" alt="">
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="slider_button_container">
          <div id="first_slider_button" class="slider_button"></div>
          <div id="second_slider_button" class="slider_button"></div>
          <div id="third_slider_button" class="slider_button"></div>
          <div id="fourth_slider_button" class="slider_button"></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div id="back_to_top">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/arrow_up.png" alt="back to top"></a>
      </div>
      <section id="welcome">

      </section>
      <section id="advertise">

      </section>
      <footer>

      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm not having that issue with your snippet on Chrome 56.0 for Windows. What browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: I'm having the issue on the latest version of chrome.

Comment: I've found the issue, the .fadeIn() effect of my slider was causing the picture to focus, thus the page was scrolling up. Now I will use .show() and .hide() and adjust the fade effect with css.